# how to gain Azure feature in vs2019

Tags: ssis

I'm very new to SSIS and SQL, can anyone tell me how to obtain Azure feature in visual studio 2019?
I have installed it from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/azure-feature-pack-for-integration-services-ssis?view=sql-server-ver15.
But nothing changed when I reopen SSIS, I have restart and run as administrator.
thx in advance.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNsAL.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After updating for the latest version 16.5.1, this function is well used.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to change the TargetVersion of your SSIS project. I use Visual Studio 2017, connecting to SQL Server 2017, installed the SSIS Azure feature pack for 2017, and I am only able to get my Azure components to un-grey when I change the TargetVersion to `SQL Server 2016`.

Comment: thanks for the reply, it goes well when I download Azure feature 2017 for vs2017 on my computer1, but it doesn't go well when I download Azure 2019 for vs2019 following the previous step, is it the issue of SQL Sever? lt is 2018 version.

Comment: @user618520 If your SQL Server is running 2018, you should set the TargetVersion to SQL Server 2018.

Comment: My SQL Server and SSIS are both 2019